# Ebean Groovy getAttribute: No such field in class

Tags: jpa, groovy, assert, ebean, spock

I've got three different ways to get an id from an entity.

```
e.getId()
e.getProperty('id')
InvokerHelper.getAttribute(e, 'id')
```

I'm trying to compare two entities in this fashion:

```
MemberEventEntity e = new MemberEventEntityBuilder().withBloomId(bloomId).build()
Ebean.save(e)

MemberEventEntity e2 = Ebean.find(MemberEventEntity.class, e.getId())    
assert e == e2
```

My entity is built correctly and the second entity is found correctly, however the object is an entity bean instead of an entity (this hasn't been a problem in the past).

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'member_event')
@EqualsAndHashCode(excludes = ['member', 'familyMember'])
class MemberEventEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id

    @Version
    Long version

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = 'member_id', nullable = false)
    MemberEntity member

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = 'family_member_id', nullable = true)
    FamilyMemberEntity familyMember

    @Column(name = 'event_date', nullable = false)
    LocalDate eventDate

    @Column(name = 'process_on', nullable = true)
    LocalDate processOn

    @Column(name = 'effective_date', nullable = true)
    LocalDate effectiveDate

    @Column(name = 'enrollment_available_from', nullable = false)
    LocalDate enrollmentAvailableFrom

    @Column(name = 'enrollment_available_to', nullable = false)
    LocalDate enrollmentAvailableTo

}
```

When I assert e == e2, on e2 I get an exception:

```
Failed to render value due to:

groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: id for class: com.bloomhealthco.fixtures.entities.MemberEventEntity$$EntityBean$default
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getAttribute(MetaClassImpl.java:2628)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getAttribute(MetaClassImpl.java:3466)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getAttribute(InvokerHelper.java:141)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.GroovyRuntimeUtil.getAttribute(GroovyRuntimeUtil.java:262)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.condition.DiffedObjectAsBeanRenderer.render(DiffedObjectAsBeanRenderer.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.condition.ObjectRendererService.render(ObjectRendererService.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.JUnitSupervisor.renderValue(JUnitSupervisor.java:141)
```

So clearly InvokerHelper.getAttribute is being called to satisfy the assert.  Is there a reason it can't find the property id?  Is there something in my entity that's created incorrectly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The assertion fails, and then Spock is unable to create a String representation of the bean. Unsure why.